# web_video_server installation

Tags: ros, libopencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed [web_video_server](http://wiki.ros.org/web_video_server) using the command

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-web-video-server
```

but trying to run it with `rosrun web_video_server web_video_server` gives this error:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/web_video_server/web_video_server: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core3.so.3.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm pretty sure I have opencv installed.

Running `pkg-config --cflags opencv-3.2.0-dev` gives the following output:

```
-I/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0-dev/opencv -I/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0-dev
```

Is web-video-server looking for version 3.3? How would I update to that?

I'm running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280493/web_video_server-installation/) by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2018-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` fixed the issue

---

Originally posted by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) with karma: 122 on 2018-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0